# Testing styled-components with enzyme and theme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to test styled-components with jest snapshots.

Currently, I'm using Enzyme's `mount` and my components work as expected, however, since I'm passing the whole theme my snapshots get a copy of the whole theme (as expected). However, if I change something in the theme that is not being used by my component the snapshot test fails (as expected). How do you guys normally deal with this? I want to be able to get my snapshot test to pass if the changes on the theme don't affect the component.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components. It gets rid of a lot of the noise in snapshot tests.